# Spark dataset fetching data same as header for integer column

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hive

I am trying to read hive table through spark in java, by creating a spark dataset. The data is read correctly for all columns with string headers, but for integer header, spark fetches column data same as header. The table is an external table created upon parquet file.

My hive table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `myTable`(`tester` int, `testfloat` double, `testfloat1` double, `1` double, `0` double, `455` int, `100341` int, `1String2` double, `1String3` int)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1'
)
STORED AS
  INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
  OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION 'file:/myFolderLocation/OfParquetFolder'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime' = '2174197412'
)
```

The file contents:

```
tester    testFloat    testFloat1    1    0    455    100341    1String2    1String3
1         1            1.2           1.2  1.2  1      -1        1           1
2         2            1.4           1.4  1.4  2                2           2
3         3.1          1.6           1.6  1.6  3      12        3           3
```

Hive table is created correctly,

```
1   1.0 1.2 1.2 1.2 1   -1  1.0 1
2   2.0 1.4 1.4 1.4 2   NULL    2.0 2
3   3.1 1.6 1.6 1.6 3   12  3.0 3
```

But when I create spark dataset on it,
Dataset schema:

```
 |-- tester: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- testfloat: double (nullable = true)
 |-- testfloat1: double (nullable = true)
 |-- 1: double (nullable = true)
 |-- 0: double (nullable = true)
 |-- 455: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- 100341: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- 1string2: double (nullable = true)
 |-- 1string3: integer (nullable = true)
```

dataset.show()

```
+------+---------+----------+---+---+---+------+--------+--------+
|tester|testfloat|testfloat1|  1|  0|455|100341|1string2|1string3|
+------+---------+----------+---+---+---+------+--------+--------+
|     1|      1.0|       1.2|1.0|0.0|455|100341|     1.0|       1|
|     2|      2.0|       1.4|1.0|0.0|455|100341|     2.0|       2|
|     3|      3.1|       1.6|1.0|0.0|455|100341|     3.0|       3|
+------+---------+----------+---+---+---+------+--------+--------+
```

The columns with integer header name are not being fetched correctly.

Is this due to any spark limitation?

my spark version : 2.4.4 scala 2.11
Hive version : 1.2.1000

Answer (score 0):

Failed to reproduce your error with Spark 2.1.

Can you try to add the following Spark configuration ?

```
--conf spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false
```

and load your data with :

```
spark.table("myTable").show
```

My results when trying to reproduce this bug :

```
+-----+---+---+
|a    |b  |123|
+-----+---+---+
|hello|1  |2  |
+-----+---+---+
```

printedSchema :

```
root
 |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |-- b: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- 123: integer (nullable = true)
```

Comment: HI, I am using java, I tried with SparkSession.builder().appName("sampleRecords").master("local").config("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet", false).getOrCreate(); But it is not working, also tried enableHiveSupport() for sparkSession, but even that did not work.